# Options to make error: conflicting types error as warning

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I want to know whether there is any compiler flag can be enabled to treat

> "error: conflicting types"

errors as warning. Is there any such flag exists?

Comment: why'd you want that? Fixing the root cause is infinitely better option than suppress warnings.

Comment: This looks like a real error in your code (and usually is). If you think your code is correct, then show us a code example and we can help.

Answer (score 2):

The cases of *conflicting types* **errors** cannot be removed. If it could be, what's the point of having the error message? Consider the below case

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int p = 5;
    float p = 5;

    printf("%d %f\n", p, p);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation produces

> prog.c: In function 'main':
>   prog.c:5:8: error: conflicting types for 'p'
>     float p = 5;
>            ^
>   prog.c:4:6: note: previous definition of 'p' was here
>     int p = 5;
>         ^

Here, there is a name clash of two variables. This is an error, compiler cannot continute, hence it emits the error message. If you expect this error to turn into a mere warning and continue the compilation, how can the next step can be decided? That's not possible.

---

However, a specialized case, *implicit declaration of functions* will also trigger this *warning* and with `-Werror` flag enabled, it will give error. This particular case can be bypassed (try at your own risk).

> never thtought of trying this myself

If you don't want to be *warned* for an implicit declaration (resulting *conflicting type*), you can use the `no` version of `-Wimplicit` to achieve this, I guess.